# Google Cloud Container share disk with ftp serve

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to share a persistence volumen from my Google Container Engine instance with my FTP Server instance in other to access to the file that upload to FTP server.

If I've use a Computer Engine Disk I can't do that because the disk became readonly.

I see that I can use a Cloud Storage but I don't know If I can used as persistence volumen in Container Engine.

Anybody can help me?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a FTP server container image for that. I'm not sure if anything off-the-shelf exists, you may need to build it yourself.

Then you can simply use GCE Persistent Disks as you said (however I'm not sure what you mean by "because the disk became readonly", you're supposed to explain your problem in detail at StackOverflow, people here simply can't guess it correctly all the time).

So you can follow this tutorial to learn about how to use GCE Persistent Disks on GKE clusters: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/persistent-disk then you can modify the mysql part with your FTP server docker image.

Google Cloud Storage won't give you the filesystem semantics (such as permission bits, user/group on Linux) so it probably won't suit for FTP. Also you can't mount GCS to your compute instances.

Comment: Ok, the problem with a GCE Persistent Disks is that only one instance that attach the disk can have write permission, if you attach more than one instance the other instance only have a read permission. It's not possible to attach a disk in two instance and bring write permission to both instance.

Comment: That is correct. There's currently no hosted NFS solution on Google Cloud Platform, that will let you mount a storage to multiple instances in write-mode simultaneously.